# Figure moving in Beamer when adding block and itemize

Tags: beamer, figure-placement

I try to add blocks and itemize on a frame with a figure. I want the figure not to move when adding features.

I have the above code in beamer.
I tried to restrict the size of the page but the figure is still moving when adding the itemize. Also it moves depending on the size of the itemize (going up when there are 3 items, and down where there are only 2).
I have tried to use the `\overprint` function with no success. I also tried to create a minipage for the figure without any success.
Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{structurebold}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[prefix=tikzsym]{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{\textcolor{black}{frame title}}  
     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \centering
       \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image)  at (0,0) { \includegraphics[trim = 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm,clip,width=0.5\textwidth]{lake.jpg}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
     \begin{columns}
      \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
       \onslide<2->{\begin{block}{
         \only<2>{Title1}
         \only<3-4>{Title2}}
         \begin{itemize}
           \only<2>{\item Text1
             \item text2}
         \only<3>{\item text3
             \item text4
             \item text5}
        \end{itemize}
       \end{block}}
      \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
   \only<4>{\begin{block}{
        \only<4>{title3}}
        \begin{itemize}
        \only<4>{\item text6
             \item text7}
             \vspace{0.2cm}
        \end{itemize}
     \end{block}}
    \end{column}
   \end{columns}
  \end{center}
 \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I thought i did add the document class and the packages... Thanks for your understanding and for raising this issue. I have improved the example (the figure I added is just an image with square format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest way to avoid jumping between overlays is to use a top aligned frame.

Some other comments about your code:

- `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` isn't necessary, that's the default since a couple of years
- beamer automatically loads graphicx and all the ams* packages. No need for you to load them
- beamer has its own column mechanism, no need for `\usepackage{multicol}`
- no need to load the pgf package if you've already loaded the tikz package. This will load pgf automatically
- instead of manually changing the frame title colour to black, you could change the respective beamer colour
- the tikzpicture to insert the image seems unnecessary, just insert the image itself
- the `\centering` in a tikzpicture doesn't do anything
- if you don't clip your image, you don't need all the `trim = 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm,clip`
- instead of wrapping the columns into a `minipage`, you could simply use the `totalwidth=0.95\textwidth` option
- the `center` environment around the columns won't do anything
- instead of wrapping all your titles, items etc into `\only<>{...}`, you could make use of the fact that blocks and items are overlay aware.
- If you leave your left `itemize` environment visible on the 4th overlay, you must not remove all items with `\only<3>{...}`. You cannot have an itemize environment with no items. This will cause an error

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{structurebold}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage[prefix=tikzsym]{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \frametitle{frame title}  
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \begin{columns}[totalwidth=0.95\textwidth,T]
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{block}<only@2>{Title1}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Text1
          \item text2
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
      \begin{block}<only@3->{Title2}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item text3
          \item text4
          \item text5
        \end{itemize}        
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{block}<4>{title3}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item text6
          \item text7
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very complete answer.
It works well. However, I just have another question. In this minimal example all the features are centered in the frame. However, in my template they are not. In fact, they are aligned on the left side of the frame.

Comment: @ThibÖdlaniug I don't think I understand what layout you'd like to have. Can you make a sketch?

Comment: I've just added the example of the frame. I copy/paste the code which works well but when adding on the template I used during my studies (long time ago...)

Comment: @ThibÖdlaniug Can you share the code? There seems to be something going on with the margins...

Comment: I was writting another comment while you answered. Inadvertently I set the margin to 0pt, this explains why I had this layout. I removed this.
Thanks agian for your time and help.

Comment: @ThibÖdlaniug You're welcome!